# How to get my data values sum() from past 24 hours in symfony using DQL?

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, timestamp, dql

I need to set CronJob and do calculations,
How can I reach the timestamp 24 hours ago?

```
  $queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('ema.date','data24ago'))
        ->setParameters(['member' => $member,
            'date24ago' => (new \Datetime)->getTimestamp() - 24 * 3600
            ]);
```

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set via PHP Try simply:

```
 $queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('ema.date','data24ago'))
        ->setParameters(['member' => $member,
            'date24ago' => new \Datetime('yesterday'),
            ]);
```

Comment: This is wrong  gives not a 24hours back, it gives hours to yesterday `00:00` so If I run my cron at 4 AM it takes 28hours instead of 24.

Comment: Hi @pvaitonis you are right! you can use `new \Datetime('yesterday midnight'),` instead of that. Let me know if is better  I edit my answer also

Comment: Still returns time  `00:00` of yesterday.

Comment: OK @pvaitonis sorry: last 24 hours: so you should:   `$date24ago = new \DateTime();
        $date24ago->modify('- 1 day');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon (http://carbon.nesbot.com), which is PHP library extending standard PHP \Datetime object.

Then you can just use

```
$queryBuilder
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('ema.date','data24ago'))
    ->setParameters([
        'member' => $member,
        'date24ago' => Carbon::parse('-24 hours')->getTimestamp() // or -1 day
    ]);
```